# How to search string with pattern in CallBackQueryHandler

Tags: python-telegram-bot

I have a callback_data that is a string: "Sports Hall".
I'm using the follow pattern

```
CallbackQueryHandler(tableTennisDate, pattern='Hall')
```

but I have no idea why it cant seem to identify it unless I change the pattern to "Sports" or if I just remove the word "Sports" from my callback data. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

`CallbackQueryHandler` uses regex for pattern. If you just set it as "Hall", it matches the whole word "Hall". For your case, you are trying to match "Sports Hall" with "Hall", so you have to use regex for example, `"Hall$"`.

You can learn more about regex here: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: I believe I have tried that, but "Hall$" didn't work for me. r"\w+ Hall$"worked for me though. "Hall$" only worked for me if I changed the string I wanted to match to "SportsHall"